# Automate stuff with Javascript

Tags: javascript, web, web-scraping, automation

I want to automate some tasks as below:

For a particular url `eg:www.xyz.com`, there are list of tickets nos ..so I want to click, perform an action on it which it will result in different page..and in that page.

I need to check some already filled input boxes depending upon that..I need to add content to some other input boxes and perform submit button.

Can this type of automation be performed in js ..if yes please advise of any framework ..and if no why not and suggest any other language.

I researched quite a bit, I think it can be performed in python, but i prefer any js framework or just vanilla.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) here.

Comment: This is off-topic, but http://webdriver.io/

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can. This can be achieved using Node.js + [selenium-webdriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver) package to automate what you mentioned.

Here is the API document of selenium-webdriver: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/

Here you can find tutorial on how to create web automation scripts with JavaScript:

[BDD Web Automation Tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/cuketest/bdd-automation-01-create-and-run-the-first-sample-muy8htpqy)